# You are tossing a coin, and rolling a dice. What is the probability that you get a head in toss or an odd number in die?

Tags: probability, dice, paradoxes

Probability for tossing on heads$=0.5$
Probability of rolling on odd number on die (1 or 3 or 5)$= 0.5$
As per addition rule (A union B, A or B)
that is $0.5 + 0.5 = 1$
that seems impossible. How could it be? You could very well get a tail and an even-numbered die. Is it a paradox?

Comment: To see even more that your approach is not entirely correct, consider what your argument would say about the probability of rolling a number (any number) on the die, or either heads or tails on a toss. That probability would turn out to be 2.

Answer (score 2):

The addition rule only works for *disjoint* events (i.e. if they can't both happen). In general the rule is
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$
In this case $A$ and $B$ are independent, so you can use the rule for independent events
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B);$$
using both these rules will allow you to work out what you want.

Comment: I didnt get that right. What is the answer then? (probability that you get a head in toss or an odd number in die?) Isn't it 1?

Comment: No, it's $P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$ for independent events. This gives $0.5+0.5-0.25=0.75$.

Comment: Again, i didnt get that P(A)P(B). Is there any intersection of two sets in this example? Had P(A) been probability of picking an Ace (4/52), and P(B) been probability of picking a spade (13/52), there would have been an intersection P(A ∩ B) that is the probability of picking ace of spade (1/52). But in this case, where is the intersection? coin toss and rolling a dice are independent and mutually exclusive sets and P(A ∩ B) is zero here. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, they are independent, and consequently *not* mutually exclusive. It is entirely possible to get both a head on the coin and an odd number on the die. For independent events the rule is that you multiply the probabilities to get the intersection.